# What would happen if I put two identical particles close enough?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

Is there a repulsive force between these two particles to prevent them from being in the same point? I mean, in order to obey Pauli exclusion principle?

Comment: Yes, it's called [Pauli repulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction).

Comment: @lemon So is that means these two particles will repulse each other, but there is no real force there? Is it a force we don't know yet or it just doesn't exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no repulsive force in the way that you would describe coulomb repulsion as a force. It is sometimes interpreted as an effective force, but it isn't and there is no exchange of virtual particles as there are in fundamental forces.

The PEP does *not* prevent ideal, pointlike **fermions** from being squeezed arbitrarily close together. Indeed, they *can* occupy the same position if they have different spin. What it prevents is those fermions occupying the same quantum state or for more than two (spin-up/down for half integer spin) to occupy the same location in *phase* space (momentum $\times$ position)$^3$.

To get fermions very close together means they must occupy different spin/momentum states. It is this spread of momentum that is responsible for degeneracy pressure in a dense, degenerate fermion gas.

Comment: The origin of the PEP is not understood. For example, in Bohmian mechanics it *is* formulated as the gradient of a potential.

Comment: @lemon What is the force carrier?

Comment: @RobJeffries So we haven't find the force carrier, but we can't say that it doesn't exist, right?

Comment: @alst there is no need for one, since exchange interactions (as they are called) can be understood without appealing to a force.

Comment: @alst  We can say that since it is not a force, there is no carrier. Correlations  are not forces, they are different objects.

Comment: @RobJeffries  I thought exchange interactions are just some concepts people invented to explain such force that we don't know where it come from... Are they?

Comment: @alst if you are referring to the exchange interaction introduced for example in Hartree Fock approximation, that is a related but different story where statistical correlations are mixed with the presence of a coulomb interaction. However consequences of Pauli principle  on correlation are there also for non-interaction systems.

Comment: @GiorgioP what do you mean by saying 'they are different objects', what are they exactly, exchange interaction? But where are they from?

Comment: @alst  Formula 6 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_interaction provide what in HF theory is called exchange integral and smetimes exchange interaction. As you can see it depends on the antisymmetry of the wavefunctions but also on the existence of a Coulomb interaction. The effecto of statistics on correlation is present without any reference to interactions. In particular, it is present even for the ideal gas case.

Answer (score -1):

The effect you drafted exists in reality. 
For a gas of electrons, effects of quantum theory are noticeable. In simple terms, it is forbidden to have two electrons (or other particles) in the same place - as you mentioned. Any attempt to bunch electrons together in a small volume  causes a pressure, the degenerating pressure. If you take only two particles, you get a force instead.
This degeneracy pressure of the electron gas  prevents a white dwarf star from collapsing further.

Comment: This is a misleading answer. The PEP forbids occupation of the same phase space. Fermions can be squeezed arbitrarily close together (as long as they are pointlike and non-interacting).